# Rezising a textarea when typing

Tags: javascript, resize, textarea

I'm trying to resize a textarea when typing to adjust the textarea height with the height of the text inside. I do this with the following javascript code:

```js
function textAreaAdjust(o) 
{
  o.style.height = "1px";
  o.style.height = (o.clientHeight)+"px";  
}
```

and tried onkeydown event on my textarea:

```xml
<form:form modelAttribute="article" action="articleeditsubmit">
    <input type="submit" value="Editer" />
    <form:input path="title" /> ¨<br/>
    <form:textarea path="content"  onkeydown = "textAreaAdjust(content)"  style="width:100%;overflow:hidden"  />
    <form:hidden path="id" /><br/>                  
</form:form>
```

This code works fine with Chrome browser but with Firefox when typing a long text exceeding the height of the screen, then the browser's scrollbar appears and force the focus to the top of the page and then quickly comes back to the end of the page. This make a very bad blinking effect for the user and I'm looking to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you set the height to 1px first?
It seems that Firefox would jump to the top of the screen because the textbox shrinks in height, then jumps back down when you set the correct height.

Comment: because i need to reinit the size of my textarea before give the new height size , if not the height will increase from the last size wich are not always good if you delete text.